# Exception Handling parse int and empty string

Tags: java, string, exception, int, parseint

```
   name = full_name_input.getText(); 
   Fname = father_name_input.getText();
   cnic = father_cnic_input.getText();
   DOB = Integer.parseInt(DOB_input.getText());
   Class_V = Integer.parseInt(class_input.getText());
   prsnt_add = present_add_input.getText();
   city = city_input.getText();
   province = radio_text;

   if(name.equals("") || Fname.equals("") || cnic.equals("") || DOB==0 || Class_V==0 || prsnt_add.equals("") || city.equals("") ||  province.equals(""))
   {
       Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep(); 
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please fill all fields ! \n");
   }
```

radio_text here is actually input from radio button and it is giving an error

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

actually i want to ensure that none of the jfields remain empty by the user
and if any field remains undefined it shows a popup please fill all fields 
but when date of birth or class field or both remain unfiilled by the user it gives an error mentioned in the preeceding paragraph

Comment: That error seems pretty clear. What problem are you having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is you're checking your fields after you try to set them, but the error occurs before that. For example, if `DOB_input`'s text is "", `DOB` will throw an error trying to parse that (`Integer.parseInt()` can't deal with strings like that) before you see that it's empty. If you want to keep your if-statement, you'll have to move it above the lines where you set your values. However, to do that you'd need to tweak it a bit so you check the jfields' values. Like:

```
if(full_name_input.getText().equals("") || father_name_input.getText().equals("") ..... )
{
   Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep(); 
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please fill all fields ! \n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I bet you have a problem here:

```java
DOB = Integer.parseInt(DOB_input.getText());
Class_V = Integer.parseInt(class_input.getText());
```

Either `DOB_input` or `class_input` (or even both of them) `getText()` returns empty string. You should catch that exception and properly handle it like this:

```java
try {
  value = Integer.parseInt(input.getText());
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Illegal nuber format for field <field>");
  return;
}
```

Comment: yes the error was there i have to show the exception to the user thankx for your quick suggestion

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with parsing number from String.
Did you check on which line this happened?
I suppose that here:

DOB = Integer.parseInt(DOB_input.getText());
   Class_V = Integer.parseInt(class_input.getText());